# React useEffect is returning empty data array when page loads for the first time

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I am making an API call to firebase from useEffect and the data returned is empty when the page loads for the first time but gets populated if I make any changes to the code and save it. I want the data to be present when the page loads for the first time.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";
import Helmet from "../components/Helmet/Helmet";
import "../styles/home.css";

import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import heroImg from "../assets/images/hero-img.png";

import Services from "../services/Services";
import ProductsList from "../components/UI/ProductsList";
import Clock from "../components/UI/Clock";

import counterImg from "../assets/images/counter-timer-img.png";

const Home = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [trendingProducts, setTrendingProducts] = useState([]);
  const [bestSalesProducts, setBestSalesProducts] = useState([]);
  const [mobileProducts, setMobileProducts] = useState([]);
  const [wirelessProducts, setWirelessProducts] = useState([]);
  const [popularProducts, setPopularProducts] = useState([]);

  const year = new Date().getFullYear();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = () => {
      const db = getDatabase();
      const thumbnailRef = ref(db, "Contents/");

      onValue(thumbnailRef, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        if (data !== null) {
          Object.values(data).map((product) => {
            return setProducts((oldArray) => [...oldArray, product]);
          });
          console.log(products);
        }
      });
    };

    const filteredTrendingProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "Kids"
    );
    const filteredBestSalesProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "Entertainment"
    );
    const filteredMobileProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "LifeStyle"
    );

    const filteredWirelessProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "wireless"
    );

    const filteredPopularProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "watch"
    );

    setTrendingProducts(filteredTrendingProducts);
    setBestSalesProducts(filteredBestSalesProducts);
    setMobileProducts(filteredMobileProducts);
    setWirelessProducts(filteredWirelessProducts);
    setPopularProducts(filteredPopularProducts);
    setIsLoading(false);
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div> Loading ... </div>;
  }

  return (
   
                whileTap={{ scale: 1.2 }}
                className="buy__btn store__btn"
              >
                <Link to="/shop">Visit Store</Link>
              </motion.button>
            </Col>
            <Col lg="6" md="12" className="text-end counter__img">
              <img src={counterImg} alt="" />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </section>

      <section className="new__arrivals">
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col lg="12" className="text-center mb-5">
              <h2 className="section__title">New Arrivals</h2>
            </Col>
            <ProductsList data={mobileProducts} />
            <ProductsList data={wirelessProducts} />
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </section>
      <section className="popular_category">
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col lg="12" className="text-center mb-5">
              <h2 className="section__title">Popular in Category</h2>
            </Col>
            <ProductsList data={popularProducts} />
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </section>
    </Helmet>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I have tried adding products as the useEffect depencies but it creates an infinite loop fetching.

What do I have to do for the data to be fetched on the first page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal if `console.log(products)` right after `setProducts()` returns `undefined` because `setProducts()` is asynchronous and `products` is not updated yet when logged.

Adding `products` as a dependency will create a infinite loop because the same `useEffect` is both setting and listening to `products`.

However if you prefer, you could separate the logic for filters to a second `useEffect` and add `products` as its dependency, since the filtered are actually dependent on `products`.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchProducts = () => {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const thumbnailRef = ref(db, "Contents/");

    onValue(thumbnailRef, (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      if (data !== null) {
        Object.values(data).map((product) => {
          return setProducts((oldArray) => [...oldArray, product]);
        });
        console.log(products);
      }
    });
  };
  setIsLoading(false);
  fetchProducts();
}, []);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  const filteredTrendingProducts = products.filter(
    (item) => item.category === "Kids"
  );
  const filteredBestSalesProducts = products.filter(
    (item) => item.category === "Entertainment"
  );
  const filteredMobileProducts = products.filter(
    (item) => item.category === "LifeStyle"
  );

  const filteredWirelessProducts = products.filter(
    (item) => item.category === "wireless"
  );

  const filteredPopularProducts = products.filter(
    (item) => item.category === "watch"
  );

  setTrendingProducts(filteredTrendingProducts);
  setBestSalesProducts(filteredBestSalesProducts);
  setMobileProducts(filteredMobileProducts);
  setWirelessProducts(filteredWirelessProducts);
  setPopularProducts(filteredPopularProducts);
}, [products]);
```

Comment: It worked for me. Seem the problems were in the setting and listening to the products within the same useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

setState in react is async. Read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-setstate-method-async/#:%7E:text=Why%20setState()%20is%20async,better%20user%20experience%20and%20performance.). So when you set your state (products), it takes some time to actually update your state.

In order to fix your problem, you have 2 options.

First is to write another useEffect on your products state and move your logic there like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = () => {
      const db = getDatabase();
      const thumbnailRef = ref(db, "Contents/");

      onValue(thumbnailRef, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        if (data !== null) {
          Object.values(data).map((product) => {
            return setProducts((oldArray) => [...oldArray, product]);
          });
          console.log(products);
        }
      });
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
const filteredTrendingProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "Kids"
    );
    const filteredBestSalesProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "Entertainment"
    );
    const filteredMobileProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "LifeStyle"
    );

    const filteredWirelessProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "wireless"
    );

    const filteredPopularProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "watch"
    );

    setTrendingProducts(filteredTrendingProducts);
    setBestSalesProducts(filteredBestSalesProducts);
    setMobileProducts(filteredMobileProducts);
    setWirelessProducts(filteredWirelessProducts);
    setPopularProducts(filteredPopularProducts);
    setIsLoading(false);
}, [procuts]);
```

And the other way is to use async/await and store your products in a temp variable and use the variable instead of the state:

```js
  useEffect(async () => {
    let tempProducts = [];
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const db = await getDatabase();
      const thumbnailRef = await ref(db, "Contents/");

      await onValue(thumbnailRef, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        if (data !== null) {
          Object.values(data).map((product) => {
            tempProducts = [...products, product]
            return setProducts(tempProducts);
          });
          console.log(tempProducts);
        }
      });
    };

    const filteredTrendingProducts = tempProducts.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "Kids"
    );
    const filteredBestSalesProducts = tempProducts.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "Entertainment"
    );
    const filteredMobileProducts = tempProducts.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "LifeStyle"
    );

    const filteredWirelessProducts = tempProducts.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "wireless"
    );

    const filteredPopularProducts = tempProducts.filter(
      (item) => item.category === "watch"
    );

    setTrendingProducts(filteredTrendingProducts);
    setBestSalesProducts(filteredBestSalesProducts);
    setMobileProducts(filteredMobileProducts);
    setWirelessProducts(filteredWirelessProducts);
    setPopularProducts(filteredPopularProducts);
    setIsLoading(false);
    await fetchProducts();
  }, []);
```

You can also delete async/await if the functions are not async.